# Is it possible to represent imaginary and complex areas geometrically?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

It is straightforward to represent /verify real areas in the diagram below as sum of a small yellow square and four smaller blue right triangles.

$$ (a+b)^2 = (\sqrt{a^2+b^2} )^2 + 4 \cdot \frac12 ab $$

where $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is a inclined side of the square.Absolute value of a vector as a complex number.

It is required to geometrically represent areas in the complex plane:

$$ (a+i \,b)^2 = a^2-b^2 + 2 i \,ab $$

Four inclined sides of the small yellow square shown are all complex $ (\pm a \pm i\,b.) $

Thought $w=z^2$ mappings could help, but do not know how.

We represent $a +ib, /, a ^{ib}$  geometrically as vectors in complex plane.

However  I am unable to imagine with any degree of geometrical intuition or perception what the product $(ab\,i) $ is.

[image: RealAreas]

Comment: What is imaginary/complex area?

Comment: Trying to figure it out,for a clear idea this question is given.

Comment: When you say "it is required geometrically to represent the area $(a+bi)^2=a^2-b^2+2abi$," there is no constraint in this equation.

Comment: Interpresentation using standard complex algebra as a geometric entity with conditions normally associated with it.